# Set and reduce a variable in function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to use a variable to set a limit to the number of times a variable is called. For example, I'm trying to poll a url, but I only want to do this a few times before I escape the loop.

```
# Javascript file.
@poller =
  poll: ->
    setTimeout @request, 2500

  request: ->
    $.getScript($('.polling_wrapper').data('url'))

@startPoller = (limit = 3) ->  
  if limit == 0
    alert "I'm done."
  else
    alert limit
    poller.poll

# Javascript response from poller request.
$wrapper = $('.polling_wrapper')
$wrapper.append('rendering objects')
startPoller(limit - 1)
```

The thing I'm curious about is how to reduce this limit variable in the startPoller function, because I cannot get it to be anything other than what I initialize it to (in this case, the 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decrease the limit variable within a loop. You're not really using the variable for its purpose, are you? And you're not defining limit in the main part of the file.

So, if I got this right, you should do something like this:

```
# Javascript file.
@poller =
  poll: ->
    setTimeout @request, 2500

  request: ->
    $.getScript($('.polling_wrapper').data('url'))

@startPoller = (limit = 3) ->
  while (limit > 0)   
    alert limit
    poller.poll
    limit = limit - 1

# Javascript response from poller request.
$wrapper = $('.polling_wrapper')
$wrapper.append('rendering objects')
limit = 5 # random number here
startPoller(limit - 1) # startPoller will call poller.poll 4 times
```

Haven't tested it, but I hope it will give you an idea. :)